# How to wait for "Minus" Key input

Tags: java

I'm running a program and have a thread class instanciated called minusstop. It works, but now it basically has to wait for it, while the rest of the program is running.

```
package dimensionbot;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;


public class stopthread extends Thread {

public stopthread(){
    System.out.println("Instanciated the stopthread class.");
}

public void keyevent(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Got a key event.");
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_MINUS) {
        System.exit(MIN_PRIORITY);
        System.out.println("Got minus key pressed, shutting down system");
    }
}

}
```

It's when pressing minus it doesn't send me a message saying that the button was pressed.

Answer (score 0):

You should exit after printing the line, not before

```
if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_MINUS) {
    System.out.println("Got minus key pressed, shutting down system");
    System.exit(MIN_PRIORITY);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but that doesn't make the application stop, It just prints the message. Any idea?